# Swift Invalid update using insertRow in UITableView

Tags: swift, asynchronous, insert, tableview

I'm done with this. I'm using async func to load data from servevr

```
        APIManager.loadBlocks(block_name: block_name, offset: indexPath.row + 1) { ( blocks, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.currentBlock.items.append(contentsOf: blocks![0].items)
                    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.currentBlock.items.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                    tableView.endUpdates()
                    spinner.stopAnimating()
                    tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        }
```

And i've got

**Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (20) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'**

I've tested count of currentBlock.items before and after completion of loadBlocks. It's correct: 10 before, 20 after. But why 10 appended items counts just as 1 - inserted in the error output?

I've tried with just tableView.reloadData() - it works, but i need a normal animation of inserting.

Also i've tried

```
for item in blocks![0].items {
self.currentBlock.items.append(item)
}
```

or

```
self.currentBlock.items.insert(item, at: index)
```

Still not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are only inserting 1 row, but you are appending 10 items to your model with `append(contentsOf:)`.

You should insert the same number of rows as you append the models. The indices at which to insert rows are:

```
self.currentBlock.items.count
self.currentBlock.items.count + 1
self.currentBlock.items.count + 2
self.currentBlock.items.count + 3
...
self.currentBlock.items.count + blocks![0].items.count - 1
```

(Note that `self.currentBlock.items.count` is the value before the new models are inserted)

You can create an array of index paths containing the above rows like this:

```
let indexPathsToInsertRows = (0..<blocks![0].items.count).map { 
    IndexPath(row: self.currentBlock.items.count + $0, section: 0)
}
```

And then you can insert the new models like you did before:

```
self.currentBlock.items.append(contentsOf: blocks![0].items)
```

And insert the rows at the index paths we just calculated:

```
tableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsToInsertRows, with: .automatic)
```